# Computed interface values in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

So basically, I was looking around [discordjs's typings](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/main/packages/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts) folder and found this:

```
export interface ClientEvents {
  ...
  messageCreate: [message: Message] <- what?
  messageDelete: [message: Message | PartialMessage]
}
```

What exactly are they trying to do here? I've heard of index signatures, like in this example here:

```
interface Foo {
  [bar: string]: any
}
```

But I've never seen any syntax that resembles this in both TS and JS.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#labeled-tuple-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to jonrsharpe's comment under the question. The syntax mentioned was a variation of a tuple in TypeScript 4.0 which includes labels:

Regular tuple:

```
// has no indication of parameter names
type Range = [number, number]
```

Labelled tuple:

```
type Range = [start: number, end: number]
```

```
// spreading this labelled tuple in a function's parameters...
function getRange(...range: Range) 

// ... results in the following at compile time:
function getRange(start: number, end: number)
```

Very cool!